# Fetch only Name, Email and timestamp using Gmail APIs

Tags: python, api, gmail

Is there any way to fetch only Name, Email and time-stamp of all the mails in my Gmail? Is it possible to do this using any Python library?

Also, I would like to know whether there is a limit on daily use of API request Google accepts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the IMAPClient library. Here's the relevant function: http://imapclient.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#imapclient.IMAPClient.fetch

I don't think there would be any limits on fetching your emails over IMAP, only sending limits.